# join on mutated column postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables with different date formats, and I want to mutate on of the columns to equalise the formats, is there any way to join on a mutated a column ?

The query :

```
join table_b on table_b.date_trunc('day',day2) =  table_a.date_trunc('day',day1)
```

Is giving me

```
ERROR schema "table_b" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
join table_b on date_trunc('day',table_b.day2) =  date_trunc('day',table_a.day1)
```

BTW if both columns are of the `date` or `timestamp` types then there are no formats. If they are not then `date_trunc` will not work as posted.